# R: t-test Error: Grouping Factor must have exactly 2 levels

Tags: r

This is what my data looks like. I have 3 different Media types and 3 different strains. I am trying to see the correlation between the media type and strains on their growth (Avg value in the table)

```
> head(Casp_SD_M, 100)
        Strain Conc    Rep1   Rep2   Rep3           Media           sd         Avg
1     K56-2 WT  200 0.00900 0.0030 0.0000 100 mM Glycerol 0.0045825757 0.004000000
2     K56-2 WT  180 0.00200 0.0100 0.0020 100 mM Glycerol 0.0046188022 0.004666667
3     K56-2 WT  160 0.00000 0.0090 0.0010 100 mM Glycerol 0.0049328829 0.003333333
4     K56-2 WT  140 0.00800 0.0100 0.0020 100 mM Glycerol 0.0041633320 0.006666667
5     K56-2 WT  120 0.00400 0.0040 0.0020 100 mM Glycerol 0.0011547005 0.003333333
6     K56-2 WT  100 0.00000 0.0030 0.0060 100 mM Glycerol 0.0030000000 0.003000000
7     K56-2 WT   80 0.00000 0.0020 0.0030 100 mM Glycerol 0.0015275252 0.001666667
8     K56-2 WT   60 0.00000 0.0020 0.0050 100 mM Glycerol 0.0025166115 0.002333333
9     K56-2 WT   40 0.00700 0.0060 0.0090 100 mM Glycerol 0.0015275252 0.007333333
10    K56-2 WT   20 0.02800 0.0500 0.0470 100 mM Glycerol 0.0119303534 0.041666667
11    K56-2 WT    0 1.01800 1.0950 1.0830 100 mM Glycerol 0.0414286535 1.065333333
12   ?paaABCDE  200 0.00600 0.0090 0.0061 100 mM Glycerol 0.0017039171 0.007033333
13   ?paaABCDE  180 0.01200 0.0150 0.0180 100 mM Glycerol 0.0030000000 0.015000000
14   ?paaABCDE  160 0.00400 0.0090 0.0240 100 mM Glycerol 0.0104083300 0.012333333
15   ?paaABCDE  140 0.00500 0.0070 0.0150 100 mM Glycerol 0.0052915026 0.009000000
16   ?paaABCDE  120 0.01700 0.0180 0.0170 100 mM Glycerol 0.0005773503 0.017333333
17   ?paaABCDE  100 0.00500 0.0100 0.0230 100 mM Glycerol 0.0092915732 0.012666667
18   ?paaABCDE   80 0.01000 0.0100 0.0160 100 mM Glycerol 0.0034641016 0.012000000
19   ?paaABCDE   60 0.01100 0.0120 0.0260 100 mM Glycerol 0.0083864971 0.016333333
20   ?paaABCDE   40 0.03200 0.0300 0.0290 100 mM Glycerol 0.0015275252 0.030333333
21   ?paaABCDE   20 0.04700 0.0400 0.0460 100 mM Glycerol 0.0037859389 0.044333333
22   ?paaABCDE    0 1.09800 1.0100 1.0470 100 mM Glycerol 0.0441852162 1.051666667
23 K56-2::CatR  200 0.01600 0.0070 0.0160 100 mM Glycerol 0.0051961524 0.013000000
24 K56-2::CatR  180 0.02000 0.0120 0.0260 100 mM Glycerol 0.0070237692 0.019333333
25 K56-2::CatR  160 0.01700 0.0070 0.0180 100 mM Glycerol 0.0060827625 0.014000000
26 K56-2::CatR  140 0.02400 0.0120 0.0240 100 mM Glycerol 0.0069282032 0.020000000
27 K56-2::CatR  120 0.02700 0.0190 0.0360 100 mM Glycerol 0.0085049005 0.027333333
28 K56-2::CatR  100 0.48200 0.3740 0.3600 100 mM Glycerol 0.0667632634 0.405333333
29 K56-2::CatR   80 0.50000 0.6960 0.5660 100 mM Glycerol 0.0997262921 0.587333333
30 K56-2::CatR   60 0.86800 0.8800 0.7590 100 mM Glycerol 0.0666658333 0.835666667
31 K56-2::CatR   40 0.94200 1.0680 1.1330 100 mM Glycerol 0.0971099034 1.047666667
32 K56-2::CatR   20 1.08400 1.2090 1.0010 100 mM Glycerol 0.1047043457 1.098000000
33 K56-2::CatR    0 1.09200 1.0610 1.0845 100 mM Glycerol 0.0161735381 1.079166667
34    K56-2 WT  200 0.02545 0.0230 0.0100  100 mM Glucose 0.0083036638 0.019483333
35    K56-2 WT  180 0.02510 0.0300 0.0120  100 mM Glucose 0.0093060912 0.022366667
36    K56-2 WT  160 0.02500 0.0290 0.0110  100 mM Glucose 0.0094516313 0.021666667
37    K56-2 WT  140 0.02540 0.0300 0.0120  100 mM Glucose 0.0093516487 0.022466667
38    K56-2 WT  120 0.02520 0.0240 0.0120  100 mM Glucose 0.0072993150 0.020400000
39    K56-2 WT  100 0.02500 0.0230 0.0160  100 mM Glucose 0.0047258156 0.021333333
40    K56-2 WT   80 0.02500 0.0220 0.0130  100 mM Glucose 0.0062449980 0.020000000
41    K56-2 WT   60 0.02500 0.0220 0.0150  100 mM Glucose 0.0051316014 0.020666667
42    K56-2 WT   40 0.02535 0.0260 0.0190  100 mM Glucose 0.0038674927 0.023450000
43    K56-2 WT   20 0.05640 0.0700 0.0570  100 mM Glucose 0.0076846167 0.061133333
44    K56-2 WT    0 1.51800 1.5950 1.6830  100 mM Glucose 0.0825610885 1.598666667
45   ?paaABCDE  200 0.02530 0.0200 0.0310  100 mM Glucose 0.0055012120 0.025433333
46   ?paaABCDE  180 0.02560 0.0150 0.0280  100 mM Glucose 0.0069176104 0.022866667
47   ?paaABCDE  160 0.02520 0.0090 0.0340  100 mM Glucose 0.0126812197 0.022733333
48   ?paaABCDE  140 0.02525 0.0070 0.0250  100 mM Glucose 0.0104652202 0.019083333
49   ?paaABCDE  120 0.02585 0.0180 0.0270  100 mM Glucose 0.0048980438 0.023616667
50   ?paaABCDE  100 0.02525 0.0100 0.0330  100 mM Glucose 0.0117020297 0.022750000
51   ?paaABCDE   80 0.02550 0.0100 0.0260  100 mM Glucose 0.0090967027 0.020500000
52   ?paaABCDE   60 0.02555 0.0120 0.0360  100 mM Glucose 0.0120333218 0.024516667
53   ?paaABCDE   40 0.02660 0.0300 0.0390  100 mM Glucose 0.0064072875 0.031866667
54   ?paaABCDE   20 0.02735 0.0400 0.0560  100 mM Glucose 0.0143576054 0.041116667
55   ?paaABCDE    0 1.59800 1.5100 1.6470  100 mM Glucose 0.0694190176 1.585000000
56 K56-2::CatR  200 0.01600 0.0070 0.0160  100 mM Glucose 0.0051961524 0.013000000
57 K56-2::CatR  180 0.02000 0.0120 0.0260  100 mM Glucose 0.0070237692 0.019333333
58 K56-2::CatR  160 0.01700 0.0070 0.0180  100 mM Glucose 0.0060827625 0.014000000
59 K56-2::CatR  140 0.02400 0.0120 0.0240  100 mM Glucose 0.0069282032 0.020000000
60 K56-2::CatR  120 0.02700 0.0190 0.0360  100 mM Glucose 0.0085049005 0.027333333
61 K56-2::CatR  100 0.56000 0.6100 0.6000  100 mM Glucose 0.0264575131 0.590000000
62 K56-2::CatR   80 1.00000 1.1960 1.1660  100 mM Glucose 0.1055714608 1.120666667
63 K56-2::CatR   60 1.36800 1.3800 1.3590  100 mM Glucose 0.0105356538 1.369000000
64 K56-2::CatR   40 1.44200 1.3980 1.4330  100 mM Glucose 0.0232450712 1.424333333
65 K56-2::CatR   20 1.56000 1.5090 1.6010  100 mM Glucose 0.0460904907 1.556666667
66 K56-2::CatR    0 1.59000 1.6200 1.6000  100 mM Glucose 0.0152752523 1.603333333
67    K56-2 WT  200 0.00900 0.0230 0.0500        5 mM PAA 0.0208406654 0.027333333
68    K56-2 WT  180 0.00200 0.0300 0.0520        5 mM PAA 0.0250599282 0.028000000
69    K56-2 WT  160 0.00000 0.0290 0.0510        5 mM PAA 0.0255799401 0.026666667
70    K56-2 WT  140 0.00800 0.0300 0.0520        5 mM PAA 0.0220000000 0.030000000
71    K56-2 WT  120 0.00400 0.0240 0.0520        5 mM PAA 0.0241108551 0.026666667
72    K56-2 WT  100 0.00000 0.0230 0.0560        5 mM PAA 0.0281484162 0.026333333
73    K56-2 WT   80 0.00000 0.0220 0.0530        5 mM PAA 0.0266270539 0.025000000
74    K56-2 WT   60 0.00000 0.0220 0.0550        5 mM PAA 0.0276827263 0.025666667
75    K56-2 WT   40 0.00700 0.0260 0.0590        5 mM PAA 0.0263122278 0.030666667
76    K56-2 WT   20 0.02800 0.0700 0.0970        5 mM PAA 0.0347706773 0.065000000
77    K56-2 WT    0 1.31800 1.4150 1.4330        5 mM PAA 0.0618573628 1.388666667
78   ?paaABCDE  200 0.00600 0.0110 0.0071        5 mM PAA 0.0026274195 0.008033333
79   ?paaABCDE  180 0.01200 0.0035 0.0068        5 mM PAA 0.0042852460 0.007433333
80   ?paaABCDE  160 0.00400 0.0290 0.0074        5 mM PAA 0.0135592527 0.013466667
81   ?paaABCDE  140 0.00500 0.0270 0.0065        5 mM PAA 0.0122915960 0.012833333
82   ?paaABCDE  120 0.01700 0.0380 0.0067        5 mM PAA 0.0159519069 0.020566667
83   ?paaABCDE  100 0.00500 0.0300 0.0073        5 mM PAA 0.0138177422 0.014100000
84   ?paaABCDE   80 0.01000 0.0300 0.0066        5 mM PAA 0.0126433118 0.015533333
85   ?paaABCDE   60 0.01100 0.0320 0.0076        5 mM PAA 0.0132156473 0.016866667
86   ?paaABCDE   40 0.00320 0.0050 0.0079        5 mM PAA 0.0023713569 0.005366667
87   ?paaABCDE   20 0.00470 0.0060 0.0096        5 mM PAA 0.0025383722 0.006766667
88   ?paaABCDE    0 0.01100 0.0320 0.0076        5 mM PAA 0.0132156473 0.016866667
89 K56-2::CatR  200 0.02300 0.0330 0.0180        5 mM PAA 0.0076376262 0.024666667
90 K56-2::CatR  180 0.02000 0.0330 0.0200        5 mM PAA 0.0075055535 0.024333333
91 K56-2::CatR  160 0.03000 0.0210 0.0200        5 mM PAA 0.0055075705 0.023666667
92 K56-2::CatR  140 0.03000 0.0230 0.0210        5 mM PAA 0.0047258156 0.024666667
93 K56-2::CatR  120 0.02300 0.0200 0.0330        5 mM PAA 0.0068068593 0.025333333
94 K56-2::CatR  100 0.01800 0.0300 0.0210        5 mM PAA 0.0062449980 0.023000000
95 K56-2::CatR   80 0.02000 0.0230 0.0330        5 mM PAA 0.0068068593 0.025333333
96 K56-2::CatR   60 0.02000 0.0180 0.0330        5 mM PAA 0.0081445278 0.023666667
97 K56-2::CatR   40 0.03300 0.0200 0.0210        5 mM PAA 0.0072341781 0.024666667
98 K56-2::CatR   20 0.03300 0.0200 0.0300        5 mM PAA 0.0068068593 0.027666667
99 K56-2::CatR    0 0.02100 0.0210 0.0230        5 mM PAA 0.0011547005 0.021666667
```

`I am trying to perform t.test on my data. But I am getting an error which says Grouping Factor must have exactly 2 levels. Here is the code I was using:

```css
#Statistical Analysis
head(Casp_SD_M)
Casp_SD_M%>%
  select(Strain, Media, Avg)

Casp_SD_M

levels(Casp_SD_M$Media)
unique(Strain)

t_test_results <- t.test(Media ~ Strain,
                         data = Casp_SD_M,
                         alternative = "two.sided",
                         mu = 0,
                         paired = TRUE,
                         var.equal = TRUE,
                         conf.level = 0.95)

t_test_results
```

Comment: Quick look, it seems like Media isn't a numeric value and Strain has more than 2 groups. That makes a t-test, possibly the wrong choice. Consider `aov` and using `avg` instead of `media`.

Comment: @NoobR Thank you. Performing avo with Avg solved the problem!! Cheers.